# color the bars using Barplot function

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

I made stacked Bar plot using the barplot function in R:

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(q2[, 2:3])), col=rainbow(3), names.arg=q2[, 1], las=2, cex.names=0.5)
```

Can I modify the "col" argument in such a way that it colour the bars in the bar plot based on grouping? for example: use Red color for the first six bars followed by Green color for the next four bars and likewise.

Comment: yes. From `?barplot`: "col: a vector of colors for the bars or bar components". You can use whatever vector you want (so `col=c(rep("red", 6), rep("green", 4))` in your case...)

Comment: no problem. Though maybe next time, read the help page before posting on SO ? it does help very often